# Simple and sweet, I am the one with whom you can compete

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> A sweet little thing,
>   lots'n lots I have killed,
>   I have diminished so many,
>   so many I helped to rebuild.
>
> I have many minions,
>   but on the top, there are three,
>   controlled by each other,
>   they are not so free.
>
> You can't get rid of me,
>   it's up to me when to bid you adieu,
>   do not get confused,be warned,
>   I will surely come for you
>
> No one can stop me,
>   you are all my slaves,
>   you all are bound to me,
>   from your cradle to your graves.

This was in the sandbox, as per suggestions, I tried changing first two stanzas. This one is really simple and sweet one.

Comment: I am pretty sure the answer is sugar :)

Comment: @GintasK I would love to read full explanation

Comment: I don't understand people that answer in comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it

> Time

```
A sweet little thing,
lots'n lots I have killed,
I have diminished so many,
so many I helped to rebuild.
```

> Time can rebuild something, or destroy/kill it.

```
I have many minions,
but on the top, there are three,
controlled by each other,
they are not so free.
```

> Pretty sure it's the 3 hands of a clock/watch.

```
You can't get rid of me,
it's up to me when to bid you adieu,
do not get confused,be warned,
I will surely come for you
```

> Time will come to take us to death.

```
No one can stop me,
you are all my slaves,
you all are bound to me,
from your cradle to your graves.
```

> No one can stop time, and we have no other choice than following it.

Comment: Yup! you got it :)

Answer (score 4):

My idea

> Drugs

A sweet little thing,

lots'n lots I have killed,

I have diminished so many,

so many I helped to rebuild.

> Excessive use of Drugs kills people.. Although, if used judiciously can cure  people of allergies,etc.

I have many minions,

but on the top, 
there are three,

controlled by each other,

they are not so free.

> Not sure about this... Maybe refers that ther are only a few life-threatening drugs while others might be purely medicinal..

You can't get rid of me,

it's upto me when to bid you adieu,

do not get confused,be warned,

I will surely come for you

> People become addicted to drugs, hence, very dangerous.

No one can stop me,

you are all my slaves,

you all are bound to me,

from your cradle to your graves.

> We all take medicines since our childhood, which are a sort of drugs as well...

Comment: Frankly I was waiting for this answer.(This is not the correct answer). +1 for explanation

Answer (score 3):

Is the answer

> Sugar?

A sweet little thing,
lots'n lots I have killed,
I have diminished so many,
so many I helped to rebuild.

> Sugar can cause many diseases, like Diabetes, but it also helps other people with low sugar levels to 'rebuild'. [Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar#Health_effects)

I have many minions,
but on the top, there are three,
controlled by each other,
they are not so free.

> There are many types of sugars, but the main three could be **Fractose, Galactose and Glucose** or **Lactose, Maltose and Sucrose**. [Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar#Types_of_sugar)

You can't get rid of me,
it's upto me when to bid you adieu,
do not get confused,be warned,
I will surely come for you

> Not so sure about this one... Maybe we can't get rid of it because almost every food has some sugar in it?

No one can stop me,
you are all my slaves,
you all are bound to me,
from your cradle to your graves.

> Sugar causes addiction?

Comment: Very nice explanation (on some parts), but unfortunately not an answer!

Comment: Yeah, the second part doesn't make any sence... :)